# unable to connect codeigniter to firebase.how to do the configuration and write the model to insert and update data?

Tags: php, firebase, codeigniter

```
** this is my config/firebase.php file**
<?php

class firebase{

    
    public function  __construct($config = array())
    {
       
        
        $config['firebase_app_key'] = __DIR__ . '/../config/gfgh-6bbd-firebase-adminsdk-fivu8-11536116hw5.json';
    }

}
?>
   
**this is my model**

<?php
require '/vendor/autoload.php';
use Kreait\Firebase\Factory;

class Login_model extends CI_Model
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $factory = (new Factory())
        ->withServiceAccount('gfgh-6bbd-firebase-adminsdk-fivu8-11536116hw5.json')
        ->createFirestore();
        $this->db = $factory->database();
    }

function get_data()
    {
        $document = $this->db->get();
        return $document;
    }
}
```

** i want to insert and update data in firebase **

i am gettingthis error- Your C:\xampp\htdocs\solver\application\config/firebase.php file does not appear to contain a valid configuration array.